# Extract formatted, parseable HTML from PDF

Tags: linux, windows, pdf, python, html

How would I extract formatted, parseable HTML from a PDF file? (I could only find programs that generated HTML that is hard to parse, and struggled with handling equations.) Specifically, I would like to analyze to analyze the questions in PDF files like this: http://nysedregents.org/algebraone/118/algone12018-exam.pdf. Is there a way to do this in Windows, Linux, or Python?

Comment: What tools you have tried so far ?

Comment: I’ve tried to use pdf2htmlEX, which produces accurately formatted HTML documents, but the code contained a lot of CSS and a lot of span elements within each sentence, even if it appeared to be formatted the same throughout. This makes it hard to extract parts of a page from a the generated HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **cannot** "extract" HTML from a PDF file.

The PDF file consists of commands telling the PDF renderer where to put glyphs, lines are other primitives on the page.

HTML, on the other hand, consists of tags and text, where tags like `<b>` tell the HTML renderer to use a bold font for the text, etc. It doesn't tell the renderer *where* to put the characters, but usually the renderer decides on the layout and positions based on other information.

Now it's possible to guess the formatting of the PDF file using the position of the glyphs, and use this guess to generate HTML that may vaguely resemble the PDF file layout when rendered. Also, if the necessary tables are present (which they usually are, but there are surprises), you can also convert the glyphs to the original unicode characters.

This means any HTML conversion will remain guesswork. It will be acceptable up to a point, but for complicated formats it will fail. You'll always have to manually correct the guess.

If you want a list of tools you could use for this: That's a software recommendation, and not on-topic on this stackexchange.

Comment: Thanks for the useful explanation and suggestion on how to proceed!